# ¿En XHTML y CSS cómo usar una fuente no genérica?

Tags: css, xhtml

El libro que uso para programar en `CSS` y `XHTML` me dice como usar las etiquetas para definir una fuente en especifico pero solo con fuentes genéricas, ¿De qué manera podría hacer que los usuarios de mi pagina web vean la fuente que deseo si esta no es muy conocida?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), que te va a permitir especificar fuentes online. Entonces, si quieres usar una fuente no muy conocida pero que tienes en tu ordenador, la idea sería que la subieras a tu servidor y que la incluyeras usando la siguiente regla en tu CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: <nombre-de-la-fuente>;
  src: <origen-de-la-fuente>;
  [font-weight: <peso>];
  [font-style: <estilo>];
}
```

En esa regla:

- `font-family`: es el nombre que le estás asignando a la fuente importada, el que pondrás cuando quieras usar la fuente.
- `src`: es la dirección donde se encuentra la fuente; puede ser un valor único o una lista de valores separados por coma (`,`); y usa el formato `url(origen)` (o `local(nombre)` si quieres que el navegador use la fuente local del usuario).
- `font-weight`: (opcional) es el peso de la fuente (si quieres que sea negrita, normal, fina, etc.)
- `font-style`: (opcional) es el estilo de la fuente (si quieres que sea normal, itálica, oblícua, etc.)

---

Por ejemplo, imagínate que tienes tu propia fuente llamada MiSuperFuente.woff2 y que la has puesto en el servidor en un directorio llamado `fonts` hijo del directorio en el que se encuentra el CSS. Entonces, la regla `@font-face` sería así:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MiSuperFuente';
  src: url(./fonts/MiSuperFuente.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: Solo añadir que también se pueden cargar tipografías de otras paginas fuera de tu servidor poniendo la URL en la propiedad `src`. O usar _Google fonts_ si está ahí la tipografía que se quieres usar